# Microsoft Office pinned docs list vs Windows 10 jump list

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, taskbar

In MS Office (2013), the "recent file list" in the Open dialog allows users to pin and un-pin files and delete files from the list. In the Windows "jump list" (right-click on button for app in Taskbar) you can do the same.

These lists don't synchronize. That's annoying, especially since keeping the list in order in the open-dialog of the program is a lot easier. Is there an automated way to synchronize these two lists?

Comment: Why do you have this tagged as PowerShell?  This as nothing to do with PowerShell, not can PowerShell control this, Windows and MSOffice does. These are two separate apps, the cache file lists differently by design. You'd actually see a different history list on Win10 Task view as well. So, there literally 3 lists. well 4, if you look at the QuickAccess list in file explorer.